# Github for mac download snow leopard

Tags: macos, github

Can anyone point me in the direction of a download link for a previous version of Github mac that will work with Snow leopord? The newest version has dropped support for it : http://mac.github.com/

I've been searching but I can't find anything. Alternatively I'll look into Tower but at £40 it's steep compared to Gits Free option.

Comment: Use the command line. It's free!

Comment: Free GUI that is also pretty awesome: http://www.sourcetreeapp.com

Answer (score 7):

The download link on mac.github.com is to https://central.github.com/mac/latest.

To see what the redirect is I use curl -D  , which gives a 302 to https://github-central.s3.amazonaws.com/mac%2FGitHub%20for%20Mac%2076.zip

Winding back the version numbers I got to 2056, the last version for Snow Leopard.

Comment: here is the link with the 2056 added https://github-central.s3.amazonaws.com/mac%2FGitHub%20for%20Mac%2056.zip

Comment: Got a strange error: "This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it". Anyone know how what @user1789853 is talking about with the "winding back version numbers" bit?  :D

Comment: I'm really wondering why they have gone so far out of their way to make sure that no earlier version of github mac is available anywhere. Their FAQ confirms that no old versions are available anymore. Are they worried about support requests?  Have they changed their server API so that it's incompatible?

Answer (score -1):

you can download the app here in this link http://davidramos.porexpertos.es/2012/10/github-para-snow-leopard/

But i couldnt log in with my account so lets see if you are lucky
Thanks

Comment: The link appears broken